# Group by dateTime (Set from till)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to create a group by date function. But i don't want to get results from 00:00 till 23:59, i want to get results from 6:00 till 5:59.
Can i change date from till statement?
Example

```
Select * from Sales group by Convert(date,dateOfSell)
//set statement from 6:00 till next day 5:59
```

Comment: dateOfSell is datetime?

Comment: Yes it's a dateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First substract 6 hours from the datetime, and then cast it do a date.  Then you can group on this new date.

e.g.

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(hour,-6,dateOfSell) AS DATE),MIN(dateOfSell),MAX(dateOfSell),COUNT(*)
FROM Sales 
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(hour,-6,dateOfSell) AS DATE)
```